# Run Spark job using crontab

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cron

I have write shell script to run spark job:

```
/home/ajit/deviceAnalysis.sh
/usr/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1 --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=4 --conf spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h --class com.mmi.probes.analysis.app.StartApp --driver-memory 2g --queue deviceAnalysis ./DailyDeviceProbesAnalysis.jar
```

It is working fine by (`sh /home/ajit/deviceAnalysis.sh`). But I want to run on every 5 minutes using crontab it is running but throw exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ajit/.sparkStaging/application_1601983398886_0126/__spark_libs__9052532821082604838.zip does not exist
```

in crontab
`*/10 * * * * cd /home/ajit && sh deviceAnalysis.sh`
Please help me what should I do now